# How to model this linear programming constraint?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to model linearly (namely, linear in the variables) the fact that my variable $z_i=1$ iff $x_{i+1}=1$ and $x_i=0$ and $z_{i}=0$ in every other case and the fact that $y_i =1$ iff $x_i=1$ and $x_{i+1}=0$ and $y_i =1$ in every other case.

$x_{i+1}$ and $x_i$ are binary variables (0 or 1).

I have tried :

$z_i \geq (x_{i+1}-x_i)$
$z_i \geq 0$

$y_i \geq (x_{i}-x_{i+1})$
$y_i \geq 0$

but it does not meet the requirements...

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only doing one direction. You're missing "every other case", i.e., $z_i \leq x_{i+1}$ and $z_i \leq 1-x_i$, and similarily for $y$. Your positivity on $z$ (and $y$) are redundant as they obviously are binary variables.

Comment: That's great! Thanks ! How did you proceed to find the constraints ? I mean, is there a "formal" method that helps to identify all the constraints ? Firstly I had ideas on doing a Karnaugh table but it gave nothing

Comment: Just think through the logic and the possible cases. No particular method required.